# ¿.NET Standard se ejecuta con la eficiencia de .NET Core?

Tags: .net, .net-core, rendimiento

Tengo una librería compilada para .NET Standard y una aplicación .Net Framework que usa dicha librería. Mi duda es ¿el código de mi librería se ejecutará tan rápido como un código .Net Core o como código .NET Framework?

Comment: Saludos Benjamin, dale play a este webcast: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJnUGU1kzlU quizás te ayude a tener una mejor idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes que nada, la respuesta a tu pregunta es que .NET Standard se ejecuta con la eficiencia del framework .NET de la aplicación que lo utiliza. En tu caso con .NET Framework (ademas claro que la eficiencia también depende de como esta programada la librería)

¿Por qué esto?

[.NET Standard](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/net-standard) es mas una especificación que una librería.

> .NET Standard es una especificación formal de las API de .NET que se prevé que estén disponibles en todas las implementaciones de .NET. La finalidad de .NET Standard es establecer una mayor uniformidad en el ecosistema de .NET

O sea, es "como una interfaz" de las implementaciones de .NET (no solo NET Framework y NET Core, sino también de Mono, Xamarin - Android/iOS, UWP, Unity), y obviamente .NET 5) e incluso del sistema operativo donde se ejecute.
Así podemos hacer componentes/librerías que se puedan ejecutar bien en varios entornos o incluso en varias versiones de .NET (pero hay que tener en cuenta la compatibilidad de acuerdo a la versión).
En cada nueva versión se fueron agregando mas API a las implementaciones de NET, [puedes ver esta compatibilidad de versiones aquí.](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/dotnet-standard#versions) y tendrías que tener en cuenta porque en ca nueva versión se hizo compatible para adelante pero no para atrás por ejemplo como NET Standard 2.0 solo es compatible con NET Framework 4.6.1 en adelante

Define un conjunto uniforme de API de BCL para todas las implementaciones de .NET que se van a implementar, independientemente de la carga de trabajo.
Permite a los desarrolladores generar bibliotecas portátiles
Reduce o incluso elimina la compilación condicional de código fuente compartido debido a las API de .NET, solo para API de sistema operativo.

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- [NET Standard versiones](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/dotnet-standard#versions)
- [.NET Standard: desmitificación de .NET Core y .NET Standard (del 2017)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/september/net-standard-demystifying-net-core-and-net-standard)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia

Comment: Ok, creo que ahora ya me quedó todo claro. Si uso la librería en un proyecto de consola .NET Core, el código de la librería se ejecutará con la eficiencia de .NET Core y si la uso dentro de una aplicación de consola .NET Framework se ejecutará con la eficiencia de .NET Framework, ¿verdad?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si es asi como comentas @BenjaminLuna. Pero no te olvides que la performance tambien depende de como se codifico dicha librería

Comment: Cuando dices "codificó", ¿exactamente a qué te refieres? ¿A la calidad del código escrito?

Comment: Si la "calidad del código" (la optimización de acceso a datos, a servicios - el acceso a http request- , la asignación de memoria, cache, el uso de concatenaciones, la serializacion/deserializacion json, el uso de try/cach, exceptions, etc.) ademas de los tipos de datos utilizados, la forma de mantenerlos en memoria, recorrerlos, etc.

Comment: Muy bien, José. Muchas gracias por tus respuestas. :)